# Same array different output in consolelog

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

I have a static array and an array that I fill with ajax post function. Now I was planning to replace the static array for the dynamic one but as it turns out the two arrays seem to differ from eachother.

Array1 (static)

```
 [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object…]
  [0 … 99]
     0: Object
      data: "AFN"
      value: "Juan"
      __proto__: Object
```

array2(dynamic)

```
[Array[122]]
  0: Array[122]
    [0 … 99]
      0: Object
        data: "54, rue Royale"
        value: "Atelier graphique"
       __proto__: Object
```

I hope this makes any sense but if I need to share more information or code please let me know! The idea is to have array 2 look the same as array 1.

Comment: array2 seems to be an array of array of arrays. See if `array2[0][0]` returns the desired array.

Comment: @Salman A      **console.log(array2[0][0]);** gives me the following  **Object {value: "Atelier graphique", data: "54, rue Royale"}**

Answer (score 0):

still dont know how I got into this mess but I solved my problem with

```
var array1= array2[0].concat();
```

With help from Salman A's comment obviously.